# VBA Excel file to CSV, keeps CSV filename same as original workbook

Tags: vba, excel, csv, filenames

I am trying to find a fast way to save my `xlsx` files as `csv` files with the same file-name as the `xlsx` file (just in `csv` format). I have recorded a macro with shortcut, But the issue is that whenever I try with a new file it saves as a the same file-name I recorded initial macro with (i.e. see below, probably because I have the file labelled in code as: `3WDL_1 (2014-08-07)10secDataTable sit.csv`). Is there something I need to replace `3WDL_1 (2014-08-07)10secDataTable sit.csv` with to make the macro save with the same file-name as the actual workbook I am working with.

So basically I have a folder full of `xlsx` files and I want to use a shortcut/macro on each `xslx` file to convert them into a `csv` files that have exactly the same name as original `xlsx` file, and are saved into the same folder.

```
Sub xlstocsv()
'
' xlstocsv Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+a
'
    Columns("A:A").Select
    Range("A41243").Activate
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 41231
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 41090
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 39753
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 30184
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 26385
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 13017
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 10976
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 8162
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4785
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 4503
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 774
    ActiveWindow.ScrollRow = 1
    Range("A1").Select
    ChDir "C:\Users\paddy\Desktop\NEW CSV files whole CGM date ok!"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\paddy\Desktop\NEW CSV files whole CGM date ok!\3WDL_1 (2014-08-07)10secDataTable sit.csv" _
        , FileFormat:=xlCSVMac, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Right now, you've got the file-name hard-coded in after "`ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs`" so it's saving everything with that hard-coded name.

I think you'll want to use "`ActiveWorkbook.Name`" to get the name of the current file and concatenate it into the "Filename" variable that you have there (without the file extension) with the new extension. For example:

```
"C:\Users\padd\Desktop\NEW CSV...ok!\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & ".csv")
```

This is a kind of a dirty way to do it, but it should serve your needs. Also, depending on which version of Excel you use, I think you might need to use "`ThisWorkbook`" instead of "`ActiveWorkbook`" but I'm not sure.

Comment: Maybe use `InStr` to look for *".xl"*. That would seem to cover just about any circumstances.

Comment: That definitely makes sense. Also, thanks for the edit to do the code box/tag thing! Still kind of learning how to do stuff on this site.

Comment: Sorry guys - struggling to make it work. This creates a csv file called ActiveWorkbook (I need it to be the same original filename - i.e. 3WDL_1 (2014-08-07)10secDataTable sit . So should it look like this at the end?     'Columns("A:A").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "0.00"
    Range("A1").Select
    ChDir "C:\Users\paddy\Desktop\NEW CSV files whole CGM date ok!"
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:= _
        "C:\Users\paddy\Desktop\NEW CSV files whole CGM date ok!\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".") - 1) & ".csv"
End Sub'

Comment: @jawood2005 - No worries, we all started somewhere. [SO](http://stackoverflow.com/help) can take a little getting used to. I still have the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page bookmarked for quick reference.

Comment: @Jeeped. Hi guys - would you mind just writing out the above new code you have added in full (as it would go into VBA) so I can understand what you mean. Sorry - quite new to this and am a little confused :(

Answer (score 0):

Before saving as csv, get the name of the xls file. You can use the `ActiveWorkbook.Name`property. Assuming that file is called `something.xls`(and not `.xlsx`), try this:

```
Sub Macro1()
    XLSName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 4)
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="C:\Users\Username\Desktop\" & XLSName & ".csv", _
        FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
End Sub
```

This pulls the workbook name, cuts off the last 4 characters (".xls") and then runs the Save As command appending ".csv" to that. In case your Excel file has the `xlsx` extension, change line 2 to:

```
XLSName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, Len(ActiveWorkbook.Name) - 5)
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Comment: when I replace the code after     Range("A1").Select with what you have there (using 5 for xlsx) I get the error "Expected End Sub"?

Comment: Mmh. It works for me. Two things: (1) You can remove all the 'Scrolling' lines, (2) Have you adapted the file path? I guess the path `C:\Users\Username\Desktop\` does not exist on your computer. Choose a path that does. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks again! I can get that to work but the idea was that I didn't want to have to change the filename in code everytime - I just wanted it to replicate the original using a shortcut (otherwise I may as well just save the old fashioned way with tab)?

Comment: Sorry, please help me understand your comment. My above code does save the XLSX file as a CSV file with the same name. All you need to do is to define the folder you want that to go. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

I would organize the pieces before stitching them together with standard string concatenation. Here is the relevant section of the code using the [InStr function](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/InStr-Function-85D3392C-3B1C-4232-BB18-77CD0CB8A55B).

```
Dim myPath As String, myFileName As String

myPath = "C:\Users\paddy\Desktop\NEW CSV files whole CGM date ok!"
'possible alternate that gets the environment variable USERNAME
'myPath = "C:\Users\" & Environ("USERNAME") & "\Desktop\NEW CSV files whole CGM date ok!"

'check if the folder exists and if not create it
If Not CBool(Len(Dir(myPath, vbDirectory))) Then _
    MkDir Path:=myPath


myFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(1, ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xl", vbTextCompare) - 1)
'you don't actually need .csv as the extension if you are explicitly saving as xlCSV or xlCSVMac but here is an alternate
'myFileName = Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, InStr(1, ActiveWorkbook.Name, ".xl", vbTextCompare) - 1) & ".csv"

'output to the VBE's Immediate window for checking later in case there is a problem
Debug.Print myPath & Chr(92) & myFileName

' the backslash is ASCII character 92
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=myPath & Chr(92) & myFileName, _
    FileFormat:=xlCSVMac, CreateBackup:=False
```

I'm not sure what all the scrolling was doing; it probably isn't necessary. You might want to add in the number formatting command.